# C++ How to halt execution at failed object construction?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

I have a constructor which might throw an exception, it is my understanding that once this occurs the deconstructor is called. The issue is that I have no clue how to check if the object has actually been constructed successfully.

I tried doing

```
if (objectName) {
    //keep working
} else {
    //alert that something went wrong
}
```

But I learned that you can't have a "null" object in C++ like you can in Java as a pointer always exists but might point to something which you don't want.

So then I also tried doing an additional try catch around the object instantiation but the execution just keep continuing as normal. What is the best practice to check if an object has been constructed successfully and is ready to be used?

Comment: The object is fully constructed if the exception is not thrown.

Comment: If your constructor throws, you can always catch the exception. Post some real code that illustrates what you are doing.

Comment: The best practice is not to throw unless you absolutely have to. Also, read this:  http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#ctor-exceptions

Comment: Read this and get back to us: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    Type obj;
    //keep working
}
catch (/* ... */) {
    //alert that something went wrong
}
```

`obj` is only visible within the `try` block. If the constructor throws, you're leaving the `try` block and thus `obj` does not exist. So there's no notion of a "null instance" here. Either `obj` exists and is valid, or it doesn't exist because the exception resulted in leaving the `try` block.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's actually what I've done as I described, very poorly, in the second part of my question. The issue is that the code inside the try keeps executing regardless of the object throwing the error or not, what could be causing this?

Comment: @Daniel That's not possible. If the constructor throws, the program will jump directly to the `catch` statement. The only reasonable explanation here is that you are misinterpreting what is happening. Are you really sure it's the constructor (`Type::Type()` in this case) that is throwing an exception?

Comment: Hi, I actually figured it out, check my answer below. There's also a question at the end I'd love for someone to answer.